# Admin menu hiding my Navbar

Tags: 8, toolbar

In Drupal 8, how can I stop the admin toolbar from hiding my fixed navbar when I am logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You can move your nav a bit below when you have an admin-logged in, try this :

```
body.admin-menu .navbar-fixed-top {
top: 30px; }
```

Better yet, use [Adminimal Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_theme) (Admin Theme) which should automatically take care of everything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried both of these options but neither worked.

Comment: @dharma is correct that you will need to set the value of top to something.  to take account for the toolbar.  The Bootstrap theme (https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) handles this pretty nicely, check out the toolbar.less file in starterkits directory. It changes the fixed menu's top value depending on various body classes.